# How to programatically add attendees to an Appointment without adding the appointment to their calendars

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, appointment

I need to send/save Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment objects to particular rooms' calendar/schedule. I also have to include the people who are to attend this meeting in these Appointments. However, because they have already had a different service provide them with this calendar event, I need to programatically have it so each room's schedule in outlook contains these appointments and the names of the people attending in the attending list without sending the people involved in the meeting an invitation or even have it appear on their schedule. How can this be done?

Comment: Let me know if this is unclear. It was kind of hard to write out. Some more info: basically each of our training rooms have their own outlook calendar/schedule and a screen displaying the room's appointments, and they need to show appointments and who is involved in these appointments. However, no calendar/schedule, besides the rooms' schedules, should have this appointment listed.

Comment: Better question: Can I add a non-email String to the required attendance list? The appointment just needs to list the names of the attendees not the emails

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear but you should be able just to create an appointment, add an attendees you want and then and set the SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone eg

```
        Appointment aptn = new Appointment(service);
        aptn.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

That will mean the appointment will be created but no Invitations will ever be sent.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks, Glen! That is helpful! However, that is not entirely what I'm looking for. Basically I want what you said, in the sense that no invites go out, except I don't even want the appointment to show up in the invitee's schedules/calendars. SendToNone still adds appointments to calendars. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Actually this will work for the project I'm working on. Thanks! If you know the answer to my other question I would love to hear it though

Comment: The appointment will only be added to the calendar you save it to SendToNone just controls invites being sent out (the attendee copies aren't linked in Exchange they rely on the invites and updates to CRUD in attendees calendars). You need to add validly formatted SMTP address to an Attendee list or EWS will error back to you, just fake a  domain if you only have the DisplayName.